# Wordpress question – Why am I getting this username/passwd prompt?

Tags: wordpress, mamp

Having a bit of config trouble in Wordpress and wonder if anyone can help. This has been bugging me for a while, but it could be a simple issue that I've sorely overlooked.

I am trying to work locally on a Wordpress site (through MAMP) that was built by a colleague, but after downloading the files, importing the database, and trying to access http://localhost', I'm getting the following prompt:

> "A username and password are being requested by 'localhost'. The site says: "Secure directory".

I have tried the usernames and passwords that I use for the site, database, etc, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any suggestions. The config.php file is correct as far as I can tell, and the permissions are also granted, but this is starting to bug me now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a message from apache indicating that the directory/ folder you are using has been password protected. This can be done either through the Apache config files or, I think, through htaccess.

Comment: I tried this before, and swear blind it wasn't working! Damn it! Thanks so much for clarification. Commenting out the Auth info in the .htaccess file did the trick :)